# ADFv2 Queue time

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline with a few copy activities. Some of those activities are in charge of copying large amounts of data from a storage account to the same storage account but in a compressed manner (I'm talking about a few TB of data).

After running the pipeline for a few hours I noticed that some activities show "Queue" time on the monitoring blade and I was wondering what can be the reason for that "Queue" time. And more importantly if I'm being billed for that time also because from what I understand my ADF is not doing anything.

[image: Queue time]

Can someone shed some light? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Posting this as an answer because of the comment chars limit)

After a long discussion with Azure Support and reaching out to someone at the ADF product team I got some answers:

1 - The queue time is not being billed.

2 - Initially, the orchestration ADF system puts the job in a queue and it gets "queue time" until the infrastructure picks it up and start the processing part.

3 - In my case the queue time was increasing after the job started because of a bug in the underlying backend executor (it uses Azure Batch). Apparently the executors were crashing and my job was suffering from "re-pickup" time, thus increasing the queue time. This explained why after some time I started to see that the execution time and the transferred data were decreasing. The ETA for this bugfix is at the end of the month. Additionally the job that I was executing timed out (after 7 days) and after checking the billing I confirmed that I wasn't charged a dime for it.

Comment: Was it ever resolved? My queue is at 2 hours now for job which was completed under 1 minute day before

Comment: Hi @GregorySuvalian in my case the bug was resolved, I was able to execute long running activities with normal queue times and I didn't see more of this abnormal behaviour when the processed bytes were decreasing and the queue times were increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the the chart in this [ADF Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#monitor-visually), you could find the same metrics in the example.

[image]

In fact,it's metrics in the `executionDetails` parameter.`Queue Time+ Transfer Time= Duration Time.`

> More details on the stages copy activity goes through, and the
>   corresponding steps, duration, used configurations, etc. It's not
>   recommended to parse this section as it may change.

Please refer to the [Parallel Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#parallel-copy), copy activity will create parallel tasks to transfer data internally. Activities are all in active state in both queue time and  transfer time, never stop in queue time so that it's billed during the whole duration time. I think it's inevitable loss in data transfer process and has been digested by adf internally. You could try to adjust `parallelCopies` param to see if anything changes.

If you do concern the cost, you could submit feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory) to ask for statements from Azure Team.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for the reply.

I did saw the chart that you mention, the thing is that having a Queue time of 2 seconds is not the same as having 17 hours (or 63 by now in my specific case) so that's why I was concerned about it.
Additionally the Parallel Copy is configured to auto to have maximum performance (in my case is doing 128 parallel copies).
And yeah I am concerned about the cost because having to pay for idle time without knowing what's causing it seems unfair.

Comment: @fgbaezp So,maybe you could submit feedback to azure team, especially the cost.

Comment: @fgbaezp All the documents I could found have been shared with you,if you have further deep concern about the cost of the queue time, maybe you could get official answer from the azure team. Of course, look forward to your any progress.Thanks!

Comment: @fgbaezp Hi,any progress now?

Comment: Hi @Jay Gong, please see my answer.

Comment: @fgbaezp Great! Thanks for your sharing! You could mark it for others' reference.